# Multiple popover (popover on top of popover) in boostrap 3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am looking to implement a menu that a user clicks the first level button, it has a popover effect. Then a user clicks on the second level menu, another popover shows up. I tried looking up online but there isn't much useful information. Is it doable? The mock picture has been attached below.
[image]

Comment: you could get a  play around with the `.hover()` method http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/show-dropdown-hover-amp-caret-up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to set your popover content to support html as per
   [official documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers).
2. You need to initialise your second popover after your first popover
   is triggered.

HTML:

```
<button id="firstpopover" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right">
  Popover on left
</button>

<button id="secondpopover" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-content="test" data-placement="right">  Popover on left
</button>
```

JS:

```
var second = $('#secondpopover').remove();
var first = $('#firstpopover');

second.show();
first.data('content', second);

first.popover({html: true});

first.on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
    second.popover();
})

first.on('hidden.bs.popover', function () {
    second.popover('hide');
})
```

CSS:

```
#secondpopover {
    display: none;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rfj2n9t9/11/)